# what is the part of speech of "wider and wider"?

Tags: american-english, adjectives, conjunctions, adjective-phrases

I saw some sentences using "wider and wider".but at times , i cannot get the part of speech or something like function of this phrase.

OP 1."Wolf's trot broke into a run, wider and wider were the leaps he made"

2."The application areas for photo electronic technology are becoming wider and wider

3."In recent years, the use of computers wider and wider in every field"

In these examples i posted , i only understand the second one.coz the usage of be/become+wider and wider" makes more sense than "sentence+wider and wider"

Can i situate this phrase within whatever position i want?.Does it function as either an adjective or an adverb?

Frankly,there are more examples using that phrase apart from the three OPs i mentioned.and i find the usage way too casual.

Comment: Yes, it does (act as an adjective or adverb).  Your example (3) is missing a predicate in the main clause.  In it "use" is the subject.

Comment: By the way, if you mean "option", you should spell it out, or use "opt.", rather than using "OP"; on this forum, we use "OP" to mean Original Poster (that is, you, the one who posted the question.)

Answer (score 1):

> Wolf's trot broke into a run, ***wider and wider*** were the leaps he made *[adjective modifying the noun **leaps**]*

This is an inversion often used in literature for stylistic purposes.

> The application areas for photo electronic technology are becoming ***wider and wider*** *[predicate adjective modifying the link verb **are becoming**]*

As for your third example, it is indeed not a complete sentence. The whole sentence could look something like

> In recent years, the use of computers ***[having become]*** *wider and wider* in every field, *(information circulates much faster than before)*.

Note that ***wider and wider*** is an adjective describing the noun ***use*** and ***having become*** is elided.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, number 3 is not a sentence; it has no verb.

Sentence 1 is correct grammatically, but we (AmE) would say his "steps" were "longer", not his "leaps" were "wider".

Sentence 2, as you guessed, is correct.

It functions as an adjective, usually as a *predicate adjective*. It does matter where you put it, as with any adjective, so as to make clear what it modifies. So it would not be optimal to write, for example:

- Wider and wider, she saw him open his eyes.  (*she* is not getting wider!)

But in spoken English, the above would be correctly understood.

(I'm sure there are cases where placement would be more critical, but can't think of any at the moment)

Comment: In the first example,why it uses inversion? I mean,(wider and wider were the leaps he made)..or maybe it's an non-restrictive attributive clause?

Comment: Could you tell me the non-abbreviated form of first example? Would it be like (wolf's trot broke into a run,which were the steps he made longer and longer?)...

Comment: Surely, there is a big difference between a *step* and a *leap*. And if a wolf is galloping, *leap* is a much better description than *step* for what he's doing.  And if you don't like *leap* for some reason, you could use *stride*, but *step* is much too weak a word. (Although I agree that *longer* is definitely the more appropriate adjective).